# Flutter iOS BITCODE issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, razorpay, zoom-sdk

I am using 2 dependencies in my pubspec.yml

1. Zoom [pub.dev link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_zoom_plugin)
2. Razorpay [pub.dev link](https://pub.dev/packages/razorpay_flutter)

Zoom requires to disable the bitcode for the app and razorpay needs to enable the bitcode settings. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is only an additional option which will enable them to downsize the app wherever required. Razorpay will still work even if you dont enable bitcode settings for iOS.

Comment: According to this pub.dev link:
Note for iOS: Make sure that the minimum deployment target for your app is iOS 10.0 or higher. Also, don't forget to enable bitcode for your project. And also, the changes are not working

Comment: What's the current deployment target?

Comment: Kauhik is right add the bitcode in your podfile your app will run fine with razor pay and zoom. Keep the minimum deployment target 12 there's no need to drop it to 10 or 11 cause even older iphones 5s/6/6s do can run ios 12. Keeping it to 12 will ensure you no  incompatibility problem in any dependency persist.

Comment: I tried enabling the bitcode and setting the deployment target to 12 but the build failed with same error

Comment: Can you post the error please?